# UIAutomator is unable to detect the drop-down list

Tags: android, appium, dropdown, android-uiautomator

UIAutomator is unable to detect the drop-down list. It only detects the elements behind the options box.

[my drop-down options image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgCUi.png)

I also tried to print the page source, but it didn't detect either.

I don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use UIAutomatorViewer, Appium deprecated support for UIAutomator by Google.

You need to use [appium-desktop](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop) and there I suggest to create UIAutomator2 session for Android 5+ devices.

Answer (score 0):

try using [Appium Inspector](http://www.automationtestinghub.com/appium-desktop-inspector/)

If this cannot detect the dropdown then the developer need to change the code in their app.